# React 16. alert event in setState callback is called before the graphical rendering is performed

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, callback, alert, setstate

I work with react js 16.

```
var time = this.state.time;
this.setState({time: time + 1}, function(){alert("hello, time is updated");} );
```

but the alert pops up before the time is graphically updated.

Any idea how to trigger the alert but ONLY when setState is completed ?? (I want the view updated BEFORE the alert pops up...)

Comment: Check out componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot), you can compare prevState with the current state and do wathever there...

Comment: @Beuun did you ever figure this out? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

When updating state based on existing state, you should always use callback function as React waits if there are any other state updates before it renders. So your code should look like this:

```
this.setState(
   (prevState) => ({time: prevState.time + 1}),
   () => {alert("hello, time is updated");}
);
```

In another words, **whenever your new state dependens on previous state, you should use state callback method**.

Comment: Yes but the alert still pops up BEFORE the time is graphically updated and rendered...and I want the alert to be triggered AFTER the rendered is fully performed...

Comment: Then why don't you use componentDidUpdate function?
You could do something like this: componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) { if(prevState.time !== this.state.time) { alert("hello, time is updated"); } }

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work neither. I think that the setState callback or componentDidUpdate are called AFTER the re render but BEFORE the graphical repaint. The alert is still triggered before the view is updated time increment.